# javascript: Loading the same url in different iframes, how to use only one http request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, iframe

If I have different `iframes` on a page and want to load the same `url` in each one of them, if I simply use the same `url` I can see in Developer Tools that there're as many http requests as iframes

How could I prevent this to happen, and to do only one request and that this populates all iframes?

Should I load one iframe and then clone it? This first attempt is not working

(React)

```js
  const [url, setUrl] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const request = new Request('anyurl')
    setUrl(request.url)
  }, [])

  return (
    {Object.entries(iframeArray).map(() => (
        <Iframe sandbox="" src={url} />
      ))}
  )
```

Comment: Probably not possible. I say probably because I'm not sure what would happen if you put the iframe in an SVG symbol, and used it in multiple places. Probably not a good idea either way.

Comment: One thought is use onload event of one iframe to subsequently display the others. The requests for others would be resolved from browser cache

Comment: If I do this explicitly with `cache.add` and `cache.match` I get a CORS error when trying to fetch the url

What you say is to use Chrome-out-of-the-box cache optimizations, not ideal though ... but thanks, I'm gonna give it a try!

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, the answer by @user148397 seems to be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn´t work, since each `<iframe>` acts on its own.

Other question: Why do you want to reuse them? 
If you want to load static data which can be reused, please use an ajax request to load data.

Comment: No, just creating a responsinator-like clone